# C#/MEF doesn't work with a base class without parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, mef

I have a Prim class that implements an IPrimitiveDecomposer interface for MEF and inherits Node base class.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
    }
}

public interface IPrimitiveDecomposer
{
    bool Match(Node node);
}

[Export(typeof(IPrimitiveDecomposer))]
public class Prim : Node, IPrimitiveDecomposer
{       
    public bool Match(Node node) {return true;}
}
```

However, when I inherit a class that doesn't have a parameterless constructor, MEF's ComposeParts() method cannot import the Prim object. I added the attribute of ImportingConstructor following [this page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee155691.aspx), as I got compilation error without the attribute.

```
[Export(typeof(IPrimitiveDecomposer))]
public class Prim : Node, IPrimitiveDecomposer
{
    [ImportingConstructor] 
    public Prim(int val) : base (val)
    {}

    public bool Match(Node node) {return true;}
}
```

The code that doesn't work is as follows. When you provide the parameterless constructor for the Node class, it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;

public class Node
{
    public Node(int val)
    {
    }
}

public interface IPrimitiveDecomposer
{
    bool Match(Node node);
}

[Export(typeof(IPrimitiveDecomposer))]
public class Prim : Node, IPrimitiveDecomposer
{
    [ImportingConstructor] 
    public Prim(int val) : base (val)
    {}

    public bool Match(Node node) {return true;}
}

public class Test
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IPrimitiveDecomposer), AllowRecomposition = true)]
    private IEnumerable<IPrimitiveDecomposer> PrimitiveDecomposers { get; set; }

    void mef()
    {
        // MEF
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var mef = new Test();
        mef.mef();
        var res = mef.PrimitiveDecomposers;

        foreach(var it in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(it);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ImportingConstructor` attribute only works when the parameters to the constructor are MEF exported objects.  The `Prim(int val)` constructors fails composition because MEF doesn't know what value to provide for the constructor.

This particular scenario looks like it's much more suited for a MEF factory pattern.

```
interface IPrimitiveDecomposerFactory {
  IPrimitiveDecomposer Create(int value);
}

[Export(typeof(IPrimitiveDecomposerFactory))]
sealed class PrimitiveDecomposerFactor : IPrimitiveDecomposerFactory {
  public IPrimitiveDecomposer Create(int value) {
    return new Prim(value);
  }
}
```

Now code can import the `IPrimitiveDecomposerFactory` and use it to create `IPrimitiveDecomposer` instance based on specific `int` values